# Получить высоту и ширину HTML-элемента из .NET

Tags: c#, html

- **Arrange**

HTML-страница (*строка или HtmlDocument полученный, например, с помощью HtmlAgilityPack*)

Пусть это будет YouTube

---

---

- **Actual**

Мы можем бегать по HtmlNode этого HtmlDocument либо обработать строку регулярками.

Есть 3 решения :

---

```
1) Берем из строки наименования всех классов
2) Берем css-файл с сайта
3) Пытаемся забрать у каждого элемента прописанную ширину и высоту
```

---

```
1) Берем HtmlDocument
2) Бегаем по его ChildNodes
3) В надежде в аттрибутах ищем заветные Width и Height
```

---

```
1) С помощью xPath определяем базовую разметку страницы
2) Получаем блок по xPath
3) Поднимаем html полученный путём сохранения блок -> строка -> html-файл и делаем его скриншот
4) Смотрим разрешение скриншота.
```

- **Assert**

Мы можем получить по порядку ширину и высоту каждого элемента в HtmlDocument/String

---

---

- **Blockers**

Самоадаптирующиеся под размер экрана css-элементы

**Как обойти?** Поднять локально Chromium с нужным разрешением и дебажить через соответствующий порт

---

Есть идеи?

Comment: Впервые вижу, что бы парсили размер Web элемента... Можно ради любопытства узнать, для чего такое вам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Скриншот всех nodes](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905198/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-nodes)

Если коротко: `Puppetter.js` он хорошо, как headless browser

Там же получаем у любого элемента `.getRectangle()`